# Even function of a graph with local maximum at x-axis but no local minima

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am having some problems with this question.

**Question**

Give a possible equation of a function that:

- has a single local maximum, located at the x-axis,
- has no local minima,
- is an even function, and
- has $\mathbb R$ for domain and range $[-5, \infty)$

**Attempt**

I cannot fathom how a graph can have a local maximum at the x-axis but with a range of [-5, infinity).

Initially I thought it can be a quadratic curve with the vertex at the x-axis and opens downwards. However, the range would then by [0,-infinity). So a quadrative curve does not seem possible.

I mean, how can a function with a local maximum at the x-axis have a range of [-5, infinity)? Did I miss out something? Any other functions that I have missed out? Does such a function exist?

Comment: If by range you mean codomain, and not image, then it is possible: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_function

Comment: @math, deleting my comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. As the range of the map $f$ is $[-5, \infty)$, it exists $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $-5=f(a) \le f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Therefore $f$ has a local minimum at $a$. In contradiction which the second requested point.

Comment: I tried to plot the piecewise function using Desmos and there is a local  minima. Furthermore, should the third equation be -5 + exp(x-1) instead?

Comment: @IM_LOST In fact this is not possible. I should have seen from the first minute!